# How to covert a text file into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file and am wondering how to make the values inside a dictionary. Right now I have this.

```
def load_map(map_file_name):
    my_map = open(map_file_name, 'r')
    my_line = my_map.readlines()
    dict = {}

for lines in my_line:
    my_line = lines.split()
    dict[int(my_line[0])] = ','.join(my_line[1:])
    lines.strip('\n')
    lines.split(',')
    print(lines)
```

The text file I have is

```
The Dorms
        McDonald's, 50
        Burger King, 100
        Starbucks, 120
McDonald's
        Starbucks, 50
        Taco Bell, 60
```

I need it to be in the format:

```
{'The Dorms': {'McDonalds': ' 50', 'Burger King': ' 100', 
'Starbucks': ' 120'}, 
'McDonalds': {'Starbucks': ' 50', 'Taco Bell': ' 60'}
```

Comment: instead of keeping it as normal text better create dictionary in this file and `import` it. OR use file in some more useful format - like JSON or .ini or YAML. In current version you have lines like `The Dorms` which you have to recognize and skip or create nested dictionary - so your code has to be more complex.

Comment: What is wrong with your current code, what is your question? Where does that data come from?

Comment: The current code does not currently run and I'm confused about how to make a nested list with the text file given. I am in an introductory cs course and confused about this.

Comment: _The current code does not currently run_ Can you be more specific?

Comment: Yea, so the code doesn't run I get an error for the line dict[int(my_line[0])] = ','.join(my_line[1:]) and idk what's wrong about it.

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern holds, then a line that starts with a word is a key for the outer dictionary, and a line that starts with whitespace is a key, value pair for the inner dictionary. Using defaultdict will prevent you from having to test if a key exists in the outer dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

vals = defaultdict(dict)    
with open(map_file_name, 'r') as f:
    # if the line starts with a character, it is a dict key
    # if it does not, then it is part of the value
    dict_key = None
    for line in f:    
        if re.match(r'\w', line):
            dict_key = line.strip()
        else:
            # split Starbucks, 50 on ', '
            inner_key, inner_value = line.split(', ')
            vals[dict_key][inner_key.strip()] = inner_value.strip()

>>>vals
defaultdict(dict,
            {'The Dorms': {"McDonald's": '50',
              'Burger King': '100',
              'Starbucks': '120'},
             "McDonald's": {'Starbucks': '50', 'Taco Bell': '60'}})
```

Comment: I was wondering if there's any way I could do this without importing items because I have yet to learn that in my class yet. Thank you for the help!